# How do I the determine following distribution function:

Tags: probability, proof-verification, probability-distributions

EDITED:

Tasks 2,3 have been edited as per feedback given in the comments.

---

my task is as follows:

In a data center there are 2 servers of different types. 
The probability that a problem occurs in the first year $0.2$ for server 1 and $0.3$ for server 2. Let X be the number of Servers that work without problems in the first year of operation.

1. Determine the individual probabilities $P(X = k)$ with $k = 0, 1, 2$.
2. Determine the distribution function and its graph.
3. Determine the probability that at least one server will work in the first year without problems.

---

Progress so far:

Task 1:
\begin{align*}
P(X = 2) &= 0.8 \cdot 0.7 &= 0.56 \\
P(X = 0) &= 0.2 \cdot 0.3 &= 0.06 \\
P(X = 1) &= 1 - 0.56 - 0.06 &= 0.38 \\
\end{align*}

Task 2:

I'm not entirely sure, so I have tried to copy [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function). Do I simply write $f$ as a piecewise function as follows?

$f_X(x) = \begin{cases} 0.06, \ x = 0 \\ 0.38, \ x = 1 \\ 0.56, \ x = 2 \\ 0, \ x \notin \{0, 1, 2\}\end{cases}$

As for graphing it, the wiki page seems relatively straight forward.

Task 3:

Is there a more elegant/formal/better way of just writing $\Pr(X \geq 1) = P(X = 1) + P(X = 2)$?

Comment: **Task 2**: For $f_X(x)$ you should regard the case $0, \ \text{otherwise}$. **Task 3**. $P(X\geq 1)=P(X=1)+P(X=\color{red}2)$ Maybe a typo. The rest seems fine to me.

Comment: @callculus for task 2, would you mind elaborating?

Comment: You can read the [wiki section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function#Finite) There you can see the missing case. That´s what I meant: $$f_X(x) = \begin{cases} 0.56, \ x = 0 \\ 0.38, \ x = 1 \\ 0.06, \ x = 2 \\ 0, \ \ \text{otherwise}  \end{cases}$$

Comment: @callculus oh good. I overlooked that detail on the first pass. the solutions have been edited to reflect your feedback.

Comment: It seesm OK. Only a comma is missing after $0$. Edit: Now it is perfectly correct.

Comment: **Wait!** X is the number of the functioning servers. Thus $P(X=0)$ is the probability that no server works. That means $P(X=0)=0.2\cdot 0.3=0.06$ Now the expected value is $1.5$. With your pdf the expected value is $0.5$

Comment: @callculus the task is phrased in a confusing way, but the values 0.2 and 0.3 are for the cases that the server has a problem, so the solution should all the same, shouldn't it?

Comment: Not at all. $X$ is the number of working tasks. Think about that. But you just have to exchange the numbers $0.56$ and $0.06$

Comment: @callculus ah, i see. "no servers without problems". I knew there was a double negative in there somewhere

Comment: I had the same problem :) As I said, it is easy to fix it. Just exchange the numbers 0.56 and 0.06.

Comment: Now it´s correct and the expected value is $1.5$, cheers.